# AWS Data pipeline - how to use it for incremental RDS data updates?

Tags: csv, amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, amazon-data-pipeline, amazon-aurora

I have a situation where I am using data pipeline to import data from csv file stored in S3. For initial data load, data pipeline is executing good.

Now I need to keep this database up-to-date and synced to the in-premise DB. Which mean there will be set of CSV file coming to S3 which would be the updates to some existing records, new records or deletion. I need that to be updated on RDS through data pipeline.

Question - Can data pipeline is designed for such purpose OR is just meant for one-off data load? If it can be used for incremental updates, then how do I go about it.

Any help is much appreciated!

Comment: Is oracle rds supported for data pipeline. I cannot see templates for the rds oracle, only mysql is there.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes, you need to do an update and insert (aka upsert).

If you have a table with keys: key_a, key_b and other columns: col_c, col_d you can use the following SQL:

`insert into TABLENAME (key_a, key_b, col_c, col_d) values (?,?,?,?) ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE col_c=values(col_c), col_d=values(col_d)`

Comment: Thanks Matt! this definitely has solved half of the problem. Appreciate your help. Now I trying to find out if Delete/custom SQL statements can be fired using data pipeline, let me know if you have any thoughts on that.

Answer (score 2):

Kindly refer to the aws documentation: http://docs.aws.amazon.com/datapipeline/latest/DeveloperGuide/dp-template-incrementalcopyrdstos3.html

There is a predefined template for Mysql RDS incremental upload, I personally have tried incremental uploads from mysql, sql server and redshift.
You can start with using the mysql template and edit it in architect view to get a insight of the new/additional fiels it uses and likewise create datapipeline for other RDS database as well.

Internally the Incremental requires you to provide the change column which needs to be essentially a date column, and it this changecolumn is them used in the Sql script which is like:

select * from #{table} where #{myRDSTableLastModifiedCol} >= '#{format(@scheduledStartTime, 'YYYY-MM-dd HH-mm-ss')}' and #{myRDSTableLastModifiedCol} <= '#{format(@scheduledEndTime, 'YYYY-MM-dd HH-mm-ss')}'

scheduledStartTime and scheduleEndTime are the datapipeline expression whose value depends upon your schedule.
http://docs.aws.amazon.com/datapipeline/latest/DeveloperGuide/dp-pipeline-expressions.html

and scheduletype is timeseries to execute the sql at the end of the schedule end time to guarrante that there is no data loss.

And yes deleted data cant be tracked in through datapipeline; also datapipleline would also not help if the datetime column is not there in your table, in which case i wlould prefer loading full table.

I hope i have covered pretty-much i know :)

Regards,
Varun R

Comment: Varun, thanks for your reply and apologies for the delay in getting back. Out of the box template enables export from RDS to S3(CSV), but I wanted to do the other way round to update the cloud RDS from in premise DB (csv export). I agree your comments about using date field for tracking changes and also limitation about identifying a delete. We are also evaluating other ETL tools which may help us achieve both initial and incremental loads.

Comment: @Atul is Oracle RDS supported for AWS data pipeline. I am not able to find any documentation